soprovod.sopr() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
class soprovod ():

    def sopr(self):
        textbar = Text(root, width = 50, height = 5)
        textbar.pack (anchor=SW)
        self.textbar = textbar


    def sopr_save(self):
        input = self.textbar.get("1.0",END)
        print(input)

    get_btn = Button(padx=10,text='Получить данные',font='Times_New_Roman 20 bold ')
    get_btn.config(command=sopr)
    get_btn.pack()

    get_btn2 = Button(padx=10,text='Сохранить',font='Times_New_Roman 20 bold ')
    get_btn2.config(command=sopr_save)
    get_btn2.pack()

Ошибка:
TypeError: soprovod.sopr() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'


Добавьте код, как вы это вызываете. Предполагаю, что вы пытаетесь вызвать метод sopr без создания объекта класса.

Код в сам вопрос, а не в комментарии. Комментарии для этого не предназначены

В классе вне методов не должно быть исполнимого кода. Класс тут вообще не нужен. Уберите класс, параметры self, и похоже все заработает. Прежде чем использовать объекты и классы лучше сначала почитать любой учебник по этой теме, а не тупо втаскивать код в класс, и думать что это как-то заработает.

А как по другому мне передать textbar, в другую функцию

Например, вернуть из функции, записать в переменную (вообще самый простой вариант). Либо примерно как у вас, только в классе не должно быть ничего лишнего на верхнем уровне (вне методов), и должен быть создан объект класса, потом из него вызываться методы.

Тут то и проблема, у меня в текстбаре пользователь вводит значение, а уже потом по нажатии кнопки мне нужно получить это значение, поэтому я не могу понять как мне создать объект класса правильно...
Во всех учебниках и примерах которые я нашел, нет подобного

Вот исправленный вариант с пометками в комментариях:
from tkinter import *


class Soprovod:  # <- классы нужно называть с большой буквы, скобки не обязательны (если не указан родительский класс)

    def sopr(self):
        textbar = Text(root, width = 50, height = 5)
        textbar.pack (anchor=SW)
        self.textbar = textbar


    def sopr_save(self):
        input = self.textbar.get("1.0",END)
        print(input)
    
    # <-- не должно быть никакого исполнимого кода вне методов класса


root = Tk()

soprovod = Soprovod()  # <- нужно создать объект класса

get_btn = Button(padx=10,text='Получить данные',font='Times_New_Roman 20 bold ')
get_btn.config(command=soprovod.sopr)  # <- используем метод объекта (не класса), как обработчик
get_btn.pack()

get_btn2 = Button(padx=10,text='Сохранить',font='Times_New_Roman 20 bold ')
get_btn2.config(command=soprovod.sopr_save)  # <- используем метод объекта (не класса), как обработчик
get_btn2.pack()


root.mainloop()

